# Array is not considering from the string created in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

For some reason, dynamic string created from the specific range is not considering in the array for loops. Below is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim AccrualFile As Workbook, AccrualSht As Worksheet
Dim AccrualFilePath As String
Dim UniqueNames As String, UniqueAccNames As String
Dim Lrows As Long, Lcols As Long


Sub Segregation()

AccrualFilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select Accrual Statement")

Set AccrualFile = Workbooks.Open(AccrualFilePath)
Set AccrualSht = AccrualFile.Sheets(1)

Lrows = AccrualSht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
UniqueNames = Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(""""", """"", True, Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(AccrualSht.Range("B2:B" & Lrows)))
UniqueAccNames = """""" & UniqueNames & """"""

Dim i As Long
Dim myarr() As Variant

myarr = Array(UniqueAccNames)



For i = LBound(myarr) To UBound(myarr)
    Debug.Print myarr(i)
Next

End Sub
```

Appreciate your help!!

Thank you.

Comment: You've confused a comma-separated string with comma-separated strings. `"foo, bar, baz"`, is not the same as `"foo", "bar", "baz"`.

Comment: I have tried that as well, but it is not working. @BigBen

Comment: Skip the textjoin and array and just use `WorksheetFunction.Unique`.

Comment: It shows TypeMistmatch & Runtime Error - 13 if I take only Unique formula

Comment: From my sight-read of your code, `myarr` is a single element array. The single element is a variant/string value that is filled by `UniqueAccNames` which is two quotation marks, some string and two more quotation marks. This is what would show in the debug.print. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I tried Debug.print for checking the Double Quotes, but somewhere it is considering the entire Values as one string

Comment: @mrk777 The array only contains one element because you only input one element into the `Array()` function. You are saving all of the text into a single string variable `UniqueNames`. If you want to create multiple elements from a single string, try the `Split` function. But @BigBen has a better solution.

Comment: Doesn't it have to be two loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WorksheetFunction.Unique` returns a (2D)<sup>1</sup> array when passed a `Range`.

```
myarr = WorksheetFunction.Unique(AccrualSht.Range("B2:B" & Lrows))

Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = LBound(myarr, 1) to Ubound(myarr, 1)
   For j = Lbound(myarr, 2) to Ubound(myarr, 2)
       Debug.Print myarr(i, j)
   Next
Next
```

<sup>1</sup> With some exceptions, including:

- When the output is a single element, it returns a 1D array.

Comment: This code is perfectly working, but can I use these values as my filter criteria in the loop itself?

Comment: I would like to use filter the range with these names one after the other... And I think I can use it